# Why partial fraction decomposition of $ \frac {1}{(x^2-3)^2 (x+7)}$ is $\frac{A}{(x+7)} + \frac {Ax+B}{x^2-3}+\frac {Cx+D}{(x^2-3)^2}$

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Why partial fraction decomposition of $ \frac {1}{(x^2-3)^2 (x+7)}$ is $\frac{A}{(x+7)} + \frac {Ax+B}{x^2-3}+\frac {Cx+D}{(x^2-3)^2}$

I am curious about its reason. I read something that are saying that this comes from Bezout Identity and idea is nothing but if we divide something by lets say degree $3$ then remainder at most can be degree $2$ like usual division.

But for here, we divide something by degree $4$ which is $(x^2-3)^2$ so why can't we directly write $ \frac {1}{(x^2-3)^2 (x+7)} = \frac{A}{(x+7)} + \frac {Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E}{(x^2-3)^2}$

Comment: The numerator over $x-3$ should be a constant. Otherwise, the fraction is not simple.

Comment: Sorry I mess up, that should be $(x^2-3)$ not $x-3$

Comment: I want to ask this questions for this $\frac {1}{(x^2-3)^2 (x+7)}$. Okay, if things that I wrote for its decompositions then what should it be?

Comment: Review the theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Statement and beware that $x^2-3$ is not irreductible in $\Bbb R[x].$

Comment: Okay, roughly theorem says that you can not take square of non irreducible polynomial, right?

Comment: [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3971889/688539)

Comment: [and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650114/why-do-we-need-a-bx-term-for-partial-fractions-with-irreducible-quadratic-fact?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C59.4533)

Comment: Right. A simple fraction is of the form $\frac{a(x)}{(p(x))^k}$ where $p$ is irreducible and $\deg a<\deg p.$

Comment: What if we encounter with this situation. What should we do? It seems to me that there should be method @AnneBauval

Comment: Note: the first letter $A$  should be a different letter, call it $H$  for example.  Meanwhile,  the final version in the question is also correct:  $ \frac {1}{(x^2-3)^2 (x+7)} = \frac{P}{(x+7)} + \frac {Qx^3+Rx^2+Sx+T}{(x^2-3)^2}$  See if you can compare the letters

Comment: To begin with, apply the statement of the theorem (linked above), i.e. write the decomposition with indeterminate coefficients (like you did, but correctly).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The numerators in partial fraction decomposition involving repeated factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244579/the-numerators-in-partial-fraction-decomposition-involving-repeated-factors) Do that for each of the three (real) roots (one simple and two double) of your denominator.